# Create hierarchy in Sax Parser JAVA

Tags: java, sax

I have done a sax parser that parses a xml file and prints the tags on the console.

The problem is that they don't follow a hierarchy.

Look at this:

```
-------------------<GOT>
-------------------<character>
-------------------<id>
-------------------<name>
----------------------->Arya Stark
-------------------<gender>
----------------------->Female
-------------------<culture>
----------------------->Northmen
-------------------<born>
----------------------->In 289 AC, at Winterfell
-------------------<died>
-------------------<alive>
----------------------->TRUE
-------------------<titles>
-------------------<title>
----------------------->Princess
```

For example, character and id are on the same level. Any idead on how to detect if a tag is a child of another?

Thanks!

```
public class Sax extends DefaultHandler {
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                            System.out.println("-------------------<" + qName + ">");

          }
      
   
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
            
            
            if( new String(ch,start,length).matches(".*[a-zA-Z0-9]+.*")){
                    System.out.println("----------------------->" + new String(ch, start, length));

        } else {
        } 
            
            
      
        }
    
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
 
        System.out.println("</" + qName + ">");
 
    
    }
}
```

This is the code of the sax parser, I need to know a way to detect if a tag has a child.

I am currently reading about sax parser, so if I find out I will post it!

```
package sax;

 
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
 
public class ParseXMLFileSax {
 
    private static final String xmlFilePath = "got.xml";
 
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
 
        try {
 
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
 
            saxParser.parse(xmlFilePath, new Sax());
 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 
    }
 
}
```

This class does the parser and calls newSaxParser class.

Comment: If you won't show us your code, how do you expect us to deal with this?

Comment: You are right, sorry

Comment: This doesn't look like you've either written a parser or are using one.

Comment: Updated the code, forgot to add the actuall parser, my bad

Answer (score 0):

SAX just a stream of events, so you should somehow maintain handler state to implement your desired logic. E.g. here there is a bunch of boolean flags

[How can I parse nested elements in SAX Parser in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388047/how-can-i-parse-nested-elements-in-sax-parser-in-java)

In your question is not clear what's exactly your goal.
If you just want to indent tags in output, you could have a integer variable for indentation, so you could increment it on element start and decrement it on element end.

Try to find some tutorial and follow it, e.g. here https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26351&seqNum=5